# For loop on a table row

Tags: javascript

Shouldn´t the code on the following page(http://plnkr.co/edit/lyq6MUBtY4jHg4l1IPlm?p=preview)

```
   let table = document.body.firstElementChild;

    for (let i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
      let row = table.rows[i];
      row.cells[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

paint ALL cells red? How does it ensure it´s only the selected ones?

Comment: It paints cell i of row i. So it's only the diagonal.

Comment: You need a for loop inside a for loop if you want to iterate over the cells of a row while iterating over all rows of the table.

Comment: Ah, I get it. So it goes 1.1,2.2,etc

Comment: @EternalDoubter maybe delete the question there is just one correctanswer and it's in the comments..

Answer (score 1):

You could use a css selector to gather all the `td` elements

[Working example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5dkwf7z/)

```
const tds = document.body.firstElementChild.querySelectorAll('td');

for (let i = i; i < tds.length; i++) {
    tds.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

If you want to ensure it's only the ones you selected, you could use a data attribute to assign them a unique id, and create a data structure that would keep track of the state for each cell, by id

Answer (score -1):

You forgot that cells is also array:

```
let table = document.body.firstElementChild;

for (let i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
   let row = table.rows[i];
   for (let j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
      row.cells[j].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
   }
 }
```

What you did was using row index to select cell index.

Comment: why second for loop?

Comment: That's really nitpick and it probably doesn't require an edit, but it's good to know that table and row could be declared using `const` since they are never reassigned

Comment: I didn´t, it´s not my code. Their code seems to work.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar he wanted to paint cells red, not rows. I just followed that ^^ That might be an difference if CSS margins are involved.

Comment: This does not answer the question.